# MediaWiki PopupPages extension not working

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I've already installed the PopupsExtension ( https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PopupPages ) and the MagicNoCache that is needed to run the Popups. I also checked my Special:Version page and everything is installed.

Then I create a random page that I called MediaWiki:Example, but when I tried to called it using the Popups Extension with the following line: `{{#popup:MediaWiki:PopupPage PopupPage | policy=cookie-out,groups-out}}` there is only a grey page that says Article Missing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have the `__NOCACHE__` magic word on MediaWiki:PopupPage? Do you get any errors in your JS console?

Comment: Where should I put this word? I have it at the top of my page, but that doesn't make any difference. Which files would you like to know in order to help me a Little bit more?

Comment: Adding to the last comment, I don't get any errors on the console, jus the following message `JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 3.0.1-pre`

Comment: I was wrong, you need to put `__NOCACHE__` on the transcluding page, i.e. in your case `MediaWiki:Example`. Perhaps also another problem might me that you're trying to do it in the MediaWiki namespace; do you get the same problem when doing it in the main namespace?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem, I just created a new Article on the main Section, I called it TestPopup and has only the following content: `__NOCACHE__TestPopup
`  Also the way im calling the popup is the next one: `__NOCACHE__{{#popup:TestPopup POPUP }}`  also I tried the line in their "example" http://www.bestpracticeswiki.net/view/Extension:PopupPages but it does not change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I decided to modify my LocalSettings.php, and then insert my own JavaScript. In that script I inject my css and html.